# ASP.NET & IIS 6.0 Verbs reset to default after upload

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, rest, iis, http-verbs

Every time I reload a project from the studio, I find that IIS overwrites the web config file. As a result, all settings are lost, including those allowed by verbs. You have to go to the Handler Mapper and rewrite the PUT and DELETE. How to fix it ?

Comment: Visual Studio? Use visual-studio tag please.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean about reload the project? Do you mean you hosted a web application on the IIS directly by using the project folder?  As far as I know, if you modify the IIS setting, it will modify the project folder's web.config file.